# автоматический unixtime в timestamp таблице mysqli

Tags: mysqli

Господа, всем лучи добра )

Создаю табличку, в ней поля тип = timestamp, insert-timestamp и update-timestamp. Все круто, дата проставляется сама. Хочется большего

Совершенно не могу найти инфу, по этому поводу, как те же timestamp делать с unixtime. Подскажите, можно ли такое реализовать? Ответ нельзя, тоже ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробовал по разному вставить UNIX_TIMESTAMP как значение по умолчанию, но ничего не получилось.

Собственно из ответа с https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331026/is-it-possible-to-create-a-column-with-a-unix-timestamp-default-in-mysql

можно увидеть 2 варианта:

- При запросе, значение timestamp вставлять в функцию unix_timestamp
- Сделать триггер, который будет автоматически перегонять timestamp в unix time

Comment: с триггером - вариант, просто думал по умолчанию такое сделать